# auto login to other site after successfully login to main site

Tags: javascript, python, flask

i have created login portal which is site (A) for users and i want to redirect them to other site (B)

i have all code and authority of site A and for site B i don't have any code and authority

site B contains of one input field where email id is require and one submit button

so what i want is user comes to site A and logins with userid and password and gets redirected to site B also i want auto input of that email in input field and auto button click

so in simple word user login to site A and redirect and also gets auto login to site B

my question is it is possible if yes then how ? which language can be used like it is possible in javascript ?

for site A i am using python flask

Comment: If the form on site B does not require a CSRF token you should be able to manually POST the email after login to site A via client side javascript.

Comment: hello @afro as i mentioned earlier that i am using flask for site A and by using redirect method of flask i am able to get redirect to destination url which is site B on successful login but i also want auto input of email on that site B. how can i do that

Comment: If you don't have access to site B code you can't. You could however POST the site B form from site A client via JavaScript after logging in, assuming site B form does not require CSRF token.

Comment: @afro could you give me some sample javascript code of logic which you are taking about and as per i know CSRF token of site B is not there

Comment: See my answer below. The code works in theory, but you may have an issue with browser Cross-Origin request

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Site B does not require CSRF token, you might be able to do something like this in the template rendered after logging in to site A:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'siteB.com/login',  // the URL site B email form makes POST to
    data: {email: '{{ email }}'}, // the email used to login at site A passed as context to the template rendered after site A login
    xhr: function() {
        return xhr;
    }
}).success(function() {
    window.location.replace(xhr.responseURL); // optionally redirect the client to the responseURL from POST made to site B
});
```